# Simple code with convertation the string into the double doesn't work

Tags: c, string

I have the code which must get the double number from the file:

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <string.h> 

FILE *fr;           

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    double elapsed_seconds;
    char line[80];
    fr = fopen ("time1.log", "rt");    
    sscanf (line, "%3.6f", &elapsed_seconds);   
    printf ("%3.6f\n", elapsed_seconds);
    fclose(fr);  
}
```

Now, time1.log contains only number 0.145213. But the program prints 0. Where is the problem?

Comment: you need to fread into `line` first...

Comment: `fgets(line, sizeof line, fr);` before `sscanf`. then `sscanf (line, "%lf", &elapsed_seconds);`

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the posted code is missing a critical line:

Not only does the code need to open the file, it also needs to read the file into the line variable.

Either insert, just after the call to `fopen()`

```
fgets( line, sizeof(line), fr );
```

or (less desirable) replace the call to `sscanf()` with

```
fscanf(fr, "%lf", &elapsed_seconds);
```

Note: if your keep the call to `sscanf()` then the format string should be: "%lf",  the same as for the call to `fscanf()`

using the call to `fscanf()` would allow the elimination of the `line[]` array.

The variable `n` is never used, so should be eliminated

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <string.h> 

FILE *fr;           

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    double elapsed_seconds;
    char line[80];
    fr = fopen ("time1.log", "rt");   
    fgets(line, 80, fr);                           // <--- Note this line
    sscanf (line, " %lf", &elapsed_seconds);   
    printf ("%3.6f\n", elapsed_seconds);
    fclose(fr);  
}
```

This is because you have to read the data from the file to the string before `sscanf`ing that string.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `sscanf` to parse the data, you need to read the data from the file - call `fgets(line,80,fr)`.